# NetBIOS master browser not available

Tags: networking, netbios, master

I´m having some problems in my network. Some machines take too long to access network shares. I´m looking for problems in NetBIOS because we don´t have a domain. I just tried to execute the `net view` command in order to get Master browser information, but neither one is master browser. So I need to know how to fix it in order to not have problems with this.

Comment: do you have more than one subnet? Do you have a WINS server configured? Masterbrowser election is usually something you don't initiate, configure, or otherwise mess with, since it generally does it all on its own.

Comment: Hi, i know its autoconfigurable so i am surprised. I dont have wins server neither domain. In my switchs only have one subnet but some machines have hamachi vpn configured, so they have two subnets. Appart from this, one server has two ethernet nic with two different ip on the same subnet (192.168.1.100 ans 192.168.1.98), one connected to each switch. I ont know if this can make troubles on the network. I dont like this, but the customer had already done this way because they access with different credentials to differen shares on the same machine.